# Openssl - cross compiled for Linux gives Bus error

Tags: openssl, cross-compiling

I have  a linux device - to which i cross compiled openssl with the following commands:

./Configure linux-generic32 shared  –DB_ENDIAN --prefix=/home --openssldir=/home

make CC=m68k-linux-gcc RANLIB=m68k-linux-ranlib LD=m68k-linux-ld MAKEDEPPROG=m68k-linux-gcc PROCESSOR=m68k

I have put the openssl binary, openss.cnf file into home dir.

and libcrypto.so.0.9.8, libssl.so.0.9.8 to the \lib folder.

Now if i launch the openssl with openssl comand - i get "Bus error". What could be the reason for it?

Comment: "Now if i launch the openssl with openssl comand" - just to cover the obvious.... You built for `m68k`. Is the machine you are running `openssl` on `m68k`? Or is it a commodity PC like `x64` or `x64`?

Comment: pls note openssl crosscompiled for m68k in x86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bus error was due to CFLAGS parameter architecture specific non-inclusion.